# Integrating exisiting Python Library to Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I've been installing few Library/Toolkit for Python like NLTK, SciPy and NumPy on my Ubuntu. I would like to try to use Anaconda distribution though. Should I remove my existing libraries before installing Anaconda?

Comment: Nop, the whole point of using something like anaconda dist is that you can use it alongside your current config. Anaconda installation should be completely independent it will not be aware of libs you installed.

Comment: Then how I uninstall existing Python packages? I tried installing from pip, but its still existing on my system

Comment: First of all: why would you want to uninstall a system library and use Anaconda instead?
Second: do not, I repeat, DO NOT uninstall python27 from system! Ubuntu, depends on python27 for a lot, if you uninstall, via "sudo apt-get remove python27" for ex. you will ruin your system.

Comment: No I only uninstall packages like numpy/scipy. I prefer conda because it is easier to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to remove your system Python. Anaconda sits alongside it. When it installs, it adds a line to your `.bashrc` that adds the Anaconda directory first in your `PATH`. This means that whenever you type `python` or `ipython` in the terminal, it will use the Anaconda Python (and the Anaconda Python will automatically use all the Anaconda Python libraries like numpy and scipy rather than the system ones). You should leave the system Python alone, as some system tools use it. The important points are:

- Whichever Python is first on your `PATH` is what gets used when you use Python in the terminal. If you create a conda environment with `conda` and use `source activate` it will put that environment first on the `PATH`.
- Each Python (Anaconda or the system) will use its own libraries and not look at the others (this is not true if you set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, but I recommend that you don't).