# Anaconda Python cannot find an installed package whereas System Python can

Tags: python, ipython, protocol-buffers, anaconda

I am using openSUSE 13.2 and have installed the Google Protocol Buffers library for Python via YaST; altogether the packages I have installed are:

```
libprotobuf-c0    -> C Bindings
libprotobuf-lite8 -> Protocol Buffers Library
libprotobuf8      -> Protocol Buffers Library
protobuf-devel    -> Headers & Libraries
python-protobuf   -> Python Bindings
```

I am new to using Anaconda and IPython Notebook but am trying to use the Protocol Buffers there.  Anaconda has installed via its standard `bash` installer to `~/anaconda` and has not modified the `PATH`.  I have successfully started IPython Notebook but when I try to access Protocol Buffers I get an error:

```
# Attempted Code
from google.protobuf import text_format

# Error
ImportError: no module named google.protobuf
```

However, when I try importing the same module when using the system-installed Python (installed via YaST and accessed via `python` at the terminal) then it imports without a problem.

Is there something special I need to do with Anaconda for it to pick up system-installed Python libraries?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215170/integrating-exisiting-python-library-to-anaconda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
conda search google....
```

Or

```
Binstar search -t conda google....
```

If someone has compiled it as a conda package and uploaded it you can install it using

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/some_user google....
```

Alternatively you might look if the package is availaible with pipy (you have to install pipy it first using conda )

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This worked although in the end I ended up using IPython directly rather than use Anaconda.  :)